# Set subtraction given two sorted vectors

Tags: c++, stl

If I have two vectors `values` and `bad_values`, is there a clean and effective way to efficiently subtract the bad values without writing my own for loop?

I know I could use

```
void set_subtraction(std::vector<int>* values, std::vector<int>* bad_values) {
    std::remove_if(values->begin(), values->end(), [bad_values](int x) {return std::find(bad_values->begin(), bad_values->end(), x) != bad_values->end()}
}
```

But that seems less readable than just writing out a loop and doesn't take advantage of both lists being sorted. It's also O(n^2) for what that's worth [although that's easily remedied by using a set for bad_values].

It's safe to assume that both vectors contain only distinct elements.

Comment: You can use standard algorithm std::set_difference.

Comment: what!?! I didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: @wrhall `set_difference` requires that your vectors are sorted.  So if your vectors are sorted, go with `set_difference`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with an example

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>


int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec1={1,2,3,4};
  std::vector<int> vec2={1,2};
  std::vector<int> result;
  std::set_difference(std::begin(vec1),std::end(vec1), 
                      std::begin(vec2),std::end(vec2), 
                      std::back_inserter(result));


 for (auto &x : result)
    std::cout<< x<<"\n";
}
```